# function undefined when using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, function, iframe

I am making browser webapp in javascript. The strange problem is, whenever I add `iframe` tag in my html. The javascript stops working.

My html:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="sean()"></button>
<iframe id="outp" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

My JS:

```
function sean(){
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var iframe = document.getElementById('outp')
iframe.src= "https://"+input
alert('worked');
};
```

The funny thing is as soon as I comment the iframe tag (not even modifying js) the function works and displays the alert message otherwise it keeps saying `sean` not defined.

Here is a pen showing error, if needed:

https://codepen.io/ShazamBolt8/pen/yLpqeXZ

If possible please add a working snippet.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = document.getElementById("txt");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let iframe = document.getElementById("ifr");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  iframe.src = "https://" + input.value;
  alert("wo4ked");
});
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" >
<button id="btn">GO</button>
<iframe id="ifr" src="about:blank" frameborder="10"></iframe>
```

Comment: Great work Steve any idea why value isn't changing in iframe?

Comment: I've edited it again for you, note that some websites don't allow their content to be on another website like Twitter, Facebook...etc, it's called X-FRAME-OPTIONS.

Comment: X-frame-options : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options